# Generate sheduler calendar from days in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a small program to generate a sheduler plan
So, the user choose:

- one or more days (ex: choosing Monday, tuesday and friday) and hours per day
- Input starDate
- Input endDate
- Input totaHours

After that, the sheduler plan is generated

From what i have right now, i'm stuck in the foreach because it generate a plan for all days

```
function isTuesday($date) {
    return date('w', strtotime($date)) === '2';
}
function isWednesday($date) {
    return date('w', strtotime($date)) === '3';
}

    foreach(range(0,365) as $day) {
    $internal_date = date(INTERNAL_FORMAT, strtotime("{$start_date} + {$day} days"));
    $this_day = date(DISPLAY_DAY_FORMAT, strtotime($internal_date));
    $this_month = date(INTERNAL_FORMAT, strtotime($internal_date));
    if ((isTuesday($internal_date) || isWednesday($internal_date)) 
        && !isExcludedDate($internal_date)) {
            $months_and_dates[$this_month][] = $this_day;
    }
    
}
```

It generates all dates from A to B dates, every Tuesday and Wednesday
let suppose i use an if statement to check if every days week are selected?
if monday, only call monday function
if monday and tuesday, monday and tuesday function
If i follow this i will have more than 30 if to cover all possibilities, any way making this shorter?

Thanks

**UPDATE 1**

If i use if, just for monday i have all this

```
foreach(range(0,$datediff) as $day) {
    $internal_date = date(INTERNAL_FORMAT, strtotime("{$startDate} + {$day} days"));
    $this_day = date(DISPLAY_DAY_FORMAT, strtotime($internal_date));
    $this_month = date(INTERNAL_FORMAT, strtotime($internal_date));
    if($isSegunda != null ){
        if ((isSegunda($internal_date)) && !isExcludedDate($internal_date)) {
            $cronograma[$this_month][] = $this_day;
    }
    }
    if($isSegunda != null && $isTerca != null){
        if ((isSegunda($internal_date)) || isTerca($internal_date) && !isExcludedDate($internal_date)) {
            $cronograma[$this_month][] = $this_day;
    }
    }
    if($isSegunda != null && $isTerca != null && $isQuarta != null){
        if ((isSegunda($internal_date)) || isTerca($internal_date) || isQuarta($internal_date) && !isExcludedDate($internal_date)) {
            $cronograma[$this_month][] = $this_day;
    }
    }
    if($isSegunda != null && $isTerca != null && $isQuarta != null && $isQuinta != null){
        if ((isSegunda($internal_date)) || isTerca($internal_date) || isQuarta($internal_date) || isQuinta($internal_date) && !isExcludedDate($internal_date)) {
            $cronograma[$this_month][] = $this_day;
    }
    }
    if($isSegunda != null && $isTerca != null && $isQuarta != null && $isQuinta != null && $isSexta !=null){
        if ((isSegunda($internal_date)) || isTerca($internal_date) || isQuarta($internal_date) || isQuinta($internal_date) || isSexta($internal_date) && !isExcludedDate($internal_date)) {
            $cronograma[$this_month][] = $this_day;
    }
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: Pleas correct me if I'm wrong, your code should: take startDate, take endDate, take week days (mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun for example), totalHours(per day or per schedule?). generate a schedule plan from start to end date only marking chosen week days and fulfilling total hours requirement and return a calendar as an array for example?

Comment: Exactly, totalHours for the all plan, not by day(for instance, i can have all monday 2 hours, and friday 3), check my update

Comment: Should the application split the total hours evenly accross all scheduled dates?

Comment: Yes, it will be better to check all sheduled dates, so anyone can check on dates x , y hours where sheduled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I created your scheduler rather the more readable way using classes

```
<?php

class Day
{
    private $free;
    private $workingHours;
    private $name;

    function __construct(string $name, bool $free, $workingHours = 0)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->free = $free;
        $this->workingHours = $workingHours;
    }

    public function setWorkingHours(int $workingHours)
    {
        $this->workingHours = $workingHours;
    }

    public function getWorkingHours(): int
    {
        return $this->workingHours;
    }

    public function isFree(): bool
    {
        return $this->free;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

class Scheduler
{
    const MONDAY = 'mon';
    const TUESDAY = 'tue';
    const WEDNESDAY = 'wed';
    const THURSDAY = 'thu';
    const FRIDAY = 'fri';
    const SATURDAY = 'sat';
    const SUNDAY = 'sun';

    public function createSchedule(\DateTime $startDate, \DateTime $endDate, int $totalHours, array $scheduledWeekDays): array
    {
        $schedule = [];
        $totalDays = 0;

        // Find all scheduled days
        while($startDate < $endDate) {
            $weekday = strtolower($startDate->format('D'));
            if ($this->isScheduledDay($weekday, $scheduledWeekDays)) {
                $schedule[] = new Day($weekday, false);
                $totalDays++;
            } else {
                $schedule[] = new Day($weekday, true);
            }
            $startDate->modify('+1days');
        }

        // Spread total hours evenly
        $hoursPerDay = floor($totalHours / $totalDays); // round it down
        $extraHours = $totalHours - ($hoursPerDay * $totalDays); // find the hours that were left by flooring

        $schedule = array_map(function(Day $day) use ($hoursPerDay) {
            if(!$day->isFree()) {
                $day->setWorkingHours($hoursPerDay);
            }

            return $day;
        }, $schedule);
        
        $lastDay = $schedule[count($schedule) - 1];
        $lastDay->setWorkingHours($lastDay->getWorkingHours() + $extraHours);

        return $schedule;
    }

    private function isScheduledDay(string $day, array $scheduledWeekDays)
    {
        return array_search($day, $scheduledWeekDays) !== false;
    }
}

$scheduler = new Scheduler();

$startDate = new \DateTime('tomorrow');
$endDate = (clone $startDate)->modify('+1week');

$schedule = $scheduler->createSchedule($startDate, $endDate, 16, [Scheduler::SATURDAY, Scheduler::SUNDAY]);

// 8 hours on saturday, and sunday
foreach($schedule as $day) {
    $text = 'Week day: ' . $day . '<br>';
    if($day->isFree()) {
        $text .= 'It\'s a free day enjoy ur time!';
    } else {
        $text .= 'Today you have to work ' . $day->getWorkingHours() . ' hours';
    }
    $text .= '<br><br>';

    echo $text;
}
```

You can extend the day class for example to represent the exact date of this day.